# Install broadcom wireless drivers without internet access

Tags: wireless, broadcom

Today I tried to install the broadcom wireless drivers on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system.

I downloaded the package and its dependencies here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionviic/bcmwl-kernel-source

Then I installed the package with `dpkg` and `apt-get` as described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366488/how-to-use-dpkg-i-to-install-package-and-dependencies-where-dependencies-are-al

However, I get the following error output which I can't even begin to understand (the .crash file tells me that an if statement has the wrong indentation):

```
...
Building initial module for 5.3.0-42-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/bcmwl-kerner-source.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.4.0-42-generic
mod probe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/5.3.0-42-eneric
...
```

Please help or tell me it is futile.

EDIT 1:

Output of `cat /var/crash/bcmwl-kernel-source.0.crash`

https://www.dropbox.com/s/v7ritbebjgtsytq/IMG_5487.jpg?dl=0

Comment: What does this tell us? `cat /var/crash/bcmwl-kernel-source.0.crash`?

Comment: edited question

Comment: Why don't you connect to internet using your phone connected to USB and install a normal way? Most likely you downloaded wrong drivers. The download link you gave is broken.

Comment: The correct link is https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/bcmwl-kernel-source

Comment: Indeed, as @Pilot6 says, you want 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5 and it appears that you tried and failed to install 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu, not the later 5 version. I think Pilot6 should propose this an the answer.

Comment: @chili555 Added as an answer.

Comment: I managed to install the drivers by tethering a friends phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried to install a wrong driver for the 5.3 kernel.

The correct link for `bcmwl-kernel-source` is

https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/bcmwl-kernel-source